# To get the content from .properties file into selenium framework

Tags: java, selenium

```
# Compulsory Dimension to create port
xOffset=-3
yOffset=50
```

How to get these xOffset and YOffset in java file.I tried with inputstream but                  not getting.These variable should get loaded in java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Properties class from Java library

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
  InputStream  inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
prop.load(inputStream);
```

The you can get the values as

```
prop.getProperty("propertyname");
```

Comment: No need for the Classloader. `getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties")` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {
  input = new FileInputStream("your_config.properties");
  prop.load(input);
  System.out.println(prop.getProperty("xOffset"));
  System.out.println(prop.getProperty("yOffset"));
} catch (IOException e) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As above explained Create a Function to read the property File During or Before Selenium Driver Constructor . So you can use them in test ( Help in Desire Capability Impl).

Store the values in Public Static final ( If you don not want to change them in Selenium and use as Default Property input)

As the values are read by Java Propertie file or .config file before selenium Driver so you can use them in Driver constructor or if you don't want you can use those properties stored as Static anywhere in the project. These values act as GLOBAL param.